# HAProxy 1.7 Statistics Setup

Tags: haproxy

I've tried multiple web tutorials for enabling HAProxy stats (just google haproxy statistics and try the top 10 links) but I believe these are for older HAProxy versions. I'm running 1.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Here's my /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file (this includes instructions given by Datadog on enabling stats).

If I remove the listen.... block, it starts fine. When it's there I get the following error:

```
sudo service haproxy stop
sudo service haproxy start
Job for haproxy.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status haproxy.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**Both journalctl and systemctl outputs show "Service started too quickly error**

```
haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-07-31 11:24:06 BST; 1min 19s ago
Docs: man:haproxy(1)
    file:/usr/share/doc/haproxy/configuration.txt.gz
Process: 1969 ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2388 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/haproxy -c -f ${CONFIG} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 2973 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f ${CONFIG} -p /run/haproxy.pid $EXTRAOPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 3511 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/haproxy -f ${CONFIG} -c -q (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 2973 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 31 11:24:06 loadbalancervm-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
```

**haproxy.cfg file**

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend LOAD_BALANCER_TIER
    bind *:80
    default_backend WEB_SERVER_TIER

backend WEB_SERVER_TIER
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    server WebServer1 192.168.1.9:80 check
    server WebServer2 192.168.1.11:80 check

listen stats :9000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm HAproxy-Statistics
    stats uri /haproxy_stats
    stats auth admin:password
```

Note that all indented lines are using tabs, not spaces. Between items are using spaces.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

You're correct about older versions.  Binding to a port on the line where the proxy (`frontend` or `listen`) declaration begins has not been valid since it was removed in HAProxy 1.5.

This is the correct form:

```
listen stats
    bind :9000
```

Note that you are already doing this in your `frontend` declarations.  A `listen` is essentially a combined frontend and backend.